# Audio not working on iOS inside React Native app with Webview and AudioContext API and WebView not appearing in Safari Develop menu

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, audiocontext

I have a React Native application that uses speech recognition and a Webview. Inside the Webview, there is a web application that plays a video and the audio is played using the AudioContext Web API. Both the audio and video are coming from a WebRTC stream.

The issue I am facing is that we cannot hear anything from WebView on iOS, but it works fine in the Safari browser. Also, it works fine on Android. The speech recognition feature is working for both platforms.

When I try to debug the Webview console on a real device using my Mac, the Safari Develop menu does not show the Web application running.

I have tried checking the permissions for the microphone and camera, and they are granted. I have also tried using different versions of React Native and WebView, but the issue persists.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, and how did you resolve it? Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated.

```
<WebView
   ref={webviewRef}
   originWhitelist={["*"]}
   style={{
       flex: 1,
       height: layout.height,
       backgroundColor: "transparent",
       ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
       top: 60,
   }}
   source={{
       uri: "WEB_APPLICATION_URL",
   }}
   mediaCapturePermissionGrantType={"grant"}
   useWebView2
   javaScriptEnabled
   javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically
   mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
   domStorageEnabled
   allowsInlineMediaPlayback
   allowFileAccessFromFileURLs
   allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs
   sharedCookiesEnabled
   thirdPartyCookiesEnabled
   mixedContentMode="compatibility"
   onMessage={handleOnMessageEvent}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<WebView
...
allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
originWhitelist={["DOMAINNAME.COM"]}
remoteDebuggingEnabled={true}
...
/>
```

allowsInlineMediaPlayback to allow audio and video to play inline rather than going full-screen, which may or may not resolve some audio issues on iOS.

remoteDebuggingEnabled will allow you to debug the WebView in the Safari Develop menu

If the issue persists, you can try using the Web Audio API instead of the AudioContext API as it is more widely supported across different browsers and platforms.